# What is the effect of PCA on the Error?

Tags: pca, elastic-net, rms

I am fitting an ElasticNet model using an array of values for alpha and l1_ratio.

I then plot the result of the negative root mean squared error from cross validation in a heatmap, which gives me the best values for these parameters.

As you can see, the results are different with and without applying the PCA.

This is an unexpected behaviour as I am not reducing the dimension of Xtrain applying PCA. Can you help me understand this strange behaviour or where I've gone wrong? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCA performs a linear combination of your original variables and defines a new set of variables. Not reducing the dimension of Xtrain after using PCA would imply that the PCA scores are able to recover all the variability from the original variables in Xtrain, so if you had a non penalized regression model, then the $R^2$ coefficient would be the same using Xtrain or using the PCA scores. But the variables themselves with which this $R^2$ coefficient is achieved are different when using Xtrain vs using PCA scores.

Now, when adding a penalization such as elastic net, you impose some additional constraints on the $\beta$ coefficients associated to the variables. Since the variables in Xtrain are different from those in the PCA scores, it is expected that the same alpha and l1_ratio values for the elastic net provide different results when using Xtrain or the PCA scores.

Comment: so this should be just related to some kind of noise as actually we are not changing the information of Xtrain right?

Comment: Since you are not changing the amount of information, just the way this infdormation is provided, my intuition is that you can expect to find very close minimum error values regardless of using Xtrain or the full PCA scores, but those error values will be found using different elastic net parameter values.